# Docker/Grafana: You may have issues with file permissions

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, grafana

**THE AIM**

I want to have access to the grafana logs on my hostsystem. For example, to open the log file with notepad++.

**WHAT DID I DO?**

I create a docker-volume and tried to map the docker-volume `grafana-storage` on the hostsystem with the folder `/var` in the docker container. There is a folder for logs and more. For this, I use the `-v`-Flag in the `docker run` statement. The whole statement here:

```
docker run --platform linux/amd64 -p 3000:3000 -v grafana-storage:/var grafana/grafana
```

Now, I get the following error:
*You may have issues with file permissions, more information here: http://docs.grafana.org/installation/docker/#migrate-to-v51-or-later
mkdir: can't create directory '/var/lib/grafana/plugins': No such file or directory
time="2023-03-18T23:13:01+01:00" level=error msg="Error waiting for container: failed to shutdown container: container d174e4fffa115d718de60010efb1f0d262d20a292b7dc3b45a1fb88d0eb2ae68 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::waitBackground: failure in a Windows system call*

I don't know how to solve that problem, but I thing it's a problem with the access permission. I hope you can help to fix it.

Thank you in forward.

Comment: Your mounting '/var` which is owned by root and the user for the official grafana image is "grafana" ... you're also overriding paths needed by the host container, mount your volume: '/var/lib/grafana` and/or look at the directory configuration ENV variables for the docker image

Comment: How can I switch the user to root? I read something about a user id  0 for root and 472 for grafana user.